# how to assign a unique domain name /IP to all outgoing traffic on AWS EC2 instances behind the load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy, amazon-elb

so I have a system that serves 100 EC2 instances. they are all behind the load balancer and they have a random pull range of IPs. 
I want to use each app server to communicate with a local server however, that local server can only whitelist a set of IP or domains (not wild card).
I have 200 EC2 with 200 IPs that regularly change and public DNS is ec2 XX.XX.XX.XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com which cannot be whitelisted because the IP varies.
the question is what would be the easiest way to make all outgoing request go out in a single IP/domain>?
I read something about reverse proxy but I do not know if that is the best way to go. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your 100 app servers have private IPs, but no public IPs presumably. So to initiate an outbound connection to your local server, they all need to route through a NAT Gateway. That NAT Gateway has a fixed Elastic IP.

Comment: well the assumption is not correct. they do have public IP. the issue is since we use load balancer, we tear ec2 down when there is no usage on the site. when we initiate new instance when the site loads come in, they will have new public IP.

Comment: Why do they all have public IPs? All inbound connections are presumably via the ELB, which itself has public IPs. A fleet of web servers behind a load balancer typically does not have or need public IPs.

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like a NAT Gateway that translates the original requesters’ IP addresses into its own fixed address before forwarding the requests.

AWS NAT Gateway documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html

Comment: Dennis, I set NAT gateway up but the issue is since all EC2 instance already have random public IP address they do noty care about NAT gateway. they can communicate outside world with their public IP.

Comment: The recommended setup is to have the instances in a private subnet that has a route table attached which routes all outgoing traffic through the NAT Gateway. The public subnets should only contain the Load Balancer for incoming requests and the NAT Gateway for outgoing requests.